# Web crawling and postgres - speeding up query that grabs new urls

Tags: postgresql

I am currently experimenting with writing a distributed web crawler for fun. I'm using PostgreSQL for data storage. I have two tables - one which holds a list of domain names, and one which holds a list of urls, and whether or not they've been scraped. The `urls` table has a `domain_id` foreign key.

When grabbing new URLs to crawl, I want to grab one URL per domain name so that I don't bombard a single server with many requests at the same time. My query looks like this:

```
select min(id) as id from urls
where scraped=0
group by domain_id
order by id
limit 50000;
```

With 150 million rows, it takes around 50 seconds for this query to run on my machine. This is too slow - it greatly limits the speed of my crawler. I have tried replacing the `group by` with a `distinct`, which actually made the query slower. Here is the result of an `explain analyze`:

```
                                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=3678510.21..3678511.46 rows=500 width=12) (actual time=59900.654..59986.473 rows=500 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=3678510.21..3678546.74 rows=14611 width=12) (actual time=59764.464..59850.255 rows=500 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (min(id))
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 59kB
         ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=3674080.47..3677782.16 rows=14611 width=12) (actual time=57876.094..59459.777 rows=3440592 loops=1)
               Group Key: domain_id
               ->  Gather Merge  (cost=3674080.47..3677489.94 rows=29222 width=12) (actual time=57876.077..58766.693 rows=4657004 loops=1)
                     Workers Planned: 2
                     Workers Launched: 2
                     ->  Sort  (cost=3673080.45..3673116.97 rows=14611 width=12) (actual time=57794.043..57982.691 rows=1552335 loops=3)
                           Sort Key: domain_id
                           Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 39576kB
                           Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 39544kB
                           Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 39616kB
                           ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=3671923.64..3672069.75 rows=14611 width=12) (actual time=52812.483..57281.723 rows=1552335 loops=3)
                                 Group Key: domain_id
                                 Batches: 101  Memory Usage: 4249kB  Disk Usage: 482144kB
                                 Worker 0:  Batches: 85  Memory Usage: 4249kB  Disk Usage: 486776kB
                                 Worker 1:  Batches: 101  Memory Usage: 4249kB  Disk Usage: 487296kB
                                 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on urls  (cost=0.00..3370185.42 rows=60347644 width=12) (actual time=68.160..45337.977 rows=48037408 loops=3)
                                       Filter: (scraped = 0)
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 2715769
 Planning Time: 0.765 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 43
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 17.414 ms, Inlining 165.549 ms, Optimization 296.330 ms, Emission 254.618 ms, Total 733.911 ms
 Execution Time: 60056.233 ms
(28 rows)
```

`urls` DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.urls (
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    domain_id int4 NOT NULL,
    url varchar NOT NULL,
    scraped int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT urls_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT urls_url_key UNIQUE (url)
);
CREATE INDEX domain_id_urls ON public.urls USING btree (domain_id);
CREATE INDEX foo ON public.urls USING btree (domain_id, scraped);
CREATE INDEX scraped ON public.urls USING btree (scraped);
CREATE INDEX urls_url ON public.urls USING btree (url);

ALTER TABLE public.urls ADD CONSTRAINT urls_domain_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (domain_id) REFERENCES domains(id);
```

Comment: add please a create table for urls

Comment: @nbk I've added the table DDL. Thanks

Comment: why do you do "order by id" ?

Comment: have you considered using a cursor instead of limit ?

Comment: I order by id so that older URLs are scraped first, so that none are left behind/forgotten about.

Comment: I don't think I understand how a cursor would help, also with multiple instances I'm not sure how feasible it would be to keep track of a cursor between them.

Comment: Everyone who runs the same query at the same time is going to get about the same answer.  How is this distributing the workload?  Rather than hitting a domain with different requests in short order, you will instead hammer it with the same request over and over again in short order.

Comment: To split it even-ish between nodes you can ad a condition like "WHERE mod(domain_id, NODE_NUMBER) = 0"

Comment: @jjanes This query is actually a subquery. The outer query sets the scraped flag to 1 so that other nodes can't grab it. Eventually I'll replace it with a timestamp so that urls can be picked up a second time.

Answer (score 1):

**Short version**

Postgres is configured to use too little memory and uses disk instead = very slow

```
SET work_mem TO '256MB';
```

Notice how the query plan doesn't mention "index" a single time? That's because it doesn't use them.

```
CREATE INDEX urls_unscraped ON public.urls USING btree
       (domain_id, url) INCLUDE (id)
       WHERE scraped=0;

VACUUM (VERBOSE, ANALYZE, FULL) urls;
```

I'd consider removing the "id" column and making domain_id+url the primary key instead.

**Long version**

Let's go through this systematically (starting from the innermost part):

```
Parallel Seq Scan on urls  (cost=0.00..3370185.42 rows=60347644 width=12)
                   (actual time=68.160..45337.977 rows=48037408 loops=3)
Filter: (scraped = 0)
```

This tells us that Postgres didn't know of a better way to fetch the correct rows than to read through every single row in the table (Seq Scan). It also tells us that the estimation of scraped vs unscraped rows was correct (the actual number of rows was close to the expected number).

```
Partial HashAggregate
  (rows=14611 width=12)
  (rows=1552335 loops=3)
  Group Key: domain_id
  Disk Usage: 482144kB
```

This doesn't look so good... Expected vs actual number of rows is off by 100x.

```
Sort 
  (rows=14611 width=12) 
  (rows=1552335 loops=3)
  Sort Key: domain_id
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 39576kB
```

Here the incorrect number of rows is expected since it the rows from the previous step. But even worse is that your database is using disk for sorting 40MB data! What does `SHOW work_mem;` say?

It's how much memory one query operation can use and the default is very conservative (4MB). If you only run a few queries at the same time I'd aim for something like 10% of your RAM. Try `SET work_mem TO '256MB';`

The rest of the query takes almost no time so no point digging into it.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't end up helping. The index didn't change the analyze - I'm not entirely sure how it would help either, since we're not doing anything with `url` other than returning it. The vacuum didn't help either, nor did increasing the work_mem to '256MB'. The query still takes over 50 seconds to run. I think the reason that the `scraped` index isn't used is because the vast majority of urls are unscraped.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to comment on the actual query.. First of all your indices should match what you query is doing and secondly they likely wont be used for queries like yours that force the database to read almost every row in the database anyway. Very simplified: fetching few rows=index faster, fetching >25% of the rows=sequential scan faster. Try setting workmem in the config file and restart postgres. Try putting a unique index on (domain_id, id) where scaped=0 then something like "select distinct on (domain_id) domain_id, id from urls where scraped=0 order domain_id, id  limit 10;"

Answer (score 0):

Your query shows a limit of 50,000, but your execution plan shows one of 500.
If you actually used 50,000 the amortized cost per row would be about 100 times lower than it is with 500, which would probably be acceptable.

You could implement a limited unique with a hash table, but PostgreSQL does not offer a plan node that does that.  But you could write a function to do that in a pl language.  You would scan the table in "id" order (omitting ones already scraped), emitting the first entry you see for each domain, which must also be the lowest-"id" one for each domain.  (Of course if the first 10 million rows all belong to just a handful of domains, you will still need to walk a bunch of the table to get more than just that handful).  A useful index or this would be:

```
create index on urls (id, domain_id) where scraped=0;
```

The filtered nature of the index wouldn't be very important now, would become so as more of the table has been scraped.

A similar method to the above would be put a limit on how much of the index/table you are willing to walk before you stop and sort the survivors.

```
select min(id) as id from 
    (select * from urls where scraped=0 order by id limit 15000) foo
group by domain_id
order by id
limit 500;
```

There is no guarantee you will actually get 500 rows out of this, for example if some small number of domains own the first 15000 unscraped urls, you will only get that number of domains.  You could increase the 15000 in the first LIMIT to counteract that, but of course that makes it less efficient as you do.  You don't seem to need a hard guarantee that you get exactly 500 rows each time, so this is probably the first thing I would do and see if it is good enough.  This would use the same index as the previous method.

Another method would be to return one row per domain with a lateral join (and then sort and limit after that, if needed)

```
select id from domain cross join lateral 
  (select id from urls where scraped=0 and  urls.domain_id=domain.domain_id order by id limit 1) foo 
order by id limit 500;
```

How efficient this will be will depend on how many distinct domains you have.  If you have a very large number, it might be even slower than your current query.  But if you have very large number of domains, then one of the previous methods should work well.  The index to best support this would be:

```
create index on urls (domain_id, id) where scraped=0;
```